# "the next" vs "next"

Tags: difference, definite-article

I would like to find out if there is any difference between "*the next*" and "*next*" when "*next*" is either an adverb (as written in some dictionaries) or a pronoun (as written in other dictionaries) or a noun (as written in still other dictionaries).

---

[thefreedictionary.com](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/next):
**(1a)** ***Next**, please*!
**(2a)** *Who is **next** (on the list)*?
[cambridge.org](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/next):
**(3a)** *Who wants to go **next***?

my variants with "the":
**(1b)** ***The next**, please*!
**(2b)** *Who is **the next** (on the list)*?
**(3b)** *Who wants to go **the next***?

Are (1b), (2b) and (3b) correct?
What's the difference between (1a), (2a), (3a) and (1b), (2b), (3b)?

---

[ldoceonline.com](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/next#next__12):
**(4a)** *Who will be **the next** to go*?
[oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/next_3):
**(5a)** ***The next** to appear was his wife*.
[thefreedictionary.com](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/next):
**(6a)** *Finish one question before you begin to answer **the next***.

my variants without "*the*":
**(4b)** *Who will be **next** to go*?
**(5b)** ***Next** to appear was his wife*.
**(6b)** *Finish one question before you begin to answer **next***.

Are (4b), (5b) and (6b) correct?
What's the difference between (4a), (5a), (6a) and (4b), (5b), (6b)?

Comment: 3b and 6b are wrong. 1b is really unnatural. 2b is unnecessarily wordy. That leaves 4 and 5. The differences between the a and b versions of both are so small they're likely never significant. I can't figure out how to explain them though. Hopefully someone else can

Comment: @gotube Why is "_Who wants to go **the next**_?" (or a similar "_Who goes **the next**_?") wrong, whereas "_Who is **the next**_?" is just unnecessarily wordy? Thanks.

Comment: In the wrong ones, "the next" must be a noun phrase, but a noun phrase doesn't fit there. In "Who is the next?", "the next" can be a noun phrase.

Comment: @gotube Does it mean: 1) since "_the next_" is used with "_the_", then "_the next_" can't be an adverb; 2) since "_go_" in "_Who goes the next_?" is intransitive, then "_goes the next_" is wrong. Thanks.

Comment: _The next_ means 'the next person or thing', so we can say "Who wants to be the next?" but not "Who wants to go the next?"